# Articles in real life

Tags: article, grammaticality

I have a question about articles in German. Is it ok to drop them from a sentence? For example, is this a weird sentence?

> Ich war in Schule.

or

> Ich gehe in Schule.

In Polish there is no need to use articles before nouns and it is hard to feel them in German.

Comment: Not only weird - it's wrong. I guess it's a common mistake made by people from all Eastern European (Slavic speaking) countries.

Comment: It's not OK with English, either: *"Is it ok to drop them from **a** sentence?"*

Comment: @splattne it's also very common among turkish and arab youngsters

Comment: @Sean Stimmt. Da rollen sich mir die Fußnägel auf.

Comment: Yes, and if you're unlucky, you'll get very xenophobic reactions for that. :( (Sad, but true, but even to me, it's one of the most annoying mistakes. Don't know why, but it really raises my pulse. ^^) So this should be #1 error to get rid of in real life!

Comment: It's Pidgin Deutsch, but I think we slowly get used to it. De Mann, de Frau, de Kind is really simpler than our present system, perhaps we should take it over.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In this case it's wrong.

The correct forms would be:

> Ich war in **der** Schule.

and

> Ich gehe in **die** Schule.

You can (have to) omit the article for toponyms:

> Ich war in Berlin.
>   Ich gehe nach Hamburg.

---

There a some cases where you can omit the article though, but you have to pay attention to the semantics:

> Sie glaubten dem Präsidenten und langjährigen Freund.

Meaning that the "Präsident" and the "Freund" are the same person while in the next sentence they are two different people:

> Sie glaubten dem Präsidenten und dem langjährigen Freund.

You can also omit the article if you're referring to a name, as in:

> Es wurde Wachtmeister Hans Meier gerufen.

Comment: Great. I didn't think of toponyms.

Comment: Very good answer!

Comment: +1 encyclopedic. :)

Comment: Nice answer @splattne. :D In the end it's better to be standard I suppose... I can risk omitting parts of speech when I'll be masterful :D

Comment: Not with *all* toponyms, especially some countries are peculiar: Ich war in der Schweiz, ich war im (=in dem) Irak, auf den Philippinen (though I don't think there are common exceptions with city names [urbanonyms] as above). And also: Ich war an der Nordsee, in den Alpen, ...

Answer (score 12):

Although grammaticaly not correct, articles are sometimes omitted when the number of words is critical, e.g. on signs. Also in transcripts and logs, articles may be ommitted sometimes.
Here's an example for a sign:

[image: Hunde-Schild]
<sub>(source: [buddelbini.de](https://www.buddelbini.de/gfx/blechschilder/as8800.jpg))</sub>

It would be correct to say: *Wenn **der** Hund kommt, ...*

However, these are rare exceptions. In spoken language and in all other forms of German texts, the usage of articles is mandatory.

Comment: awesome example and very well observed! :)

Comment: `articles are sometimes omitted when the number of words is critical, e.g. on signs.` which is observable wrong. The `der` would fit in Line 1, move the `den` to Line 2, and `warten` to Line 3, where it would fit. Signmakers surely know how to sell bigger signs or how to use smaller fonts. The idea of the sign therefore has to be, to express something with the missing word, probably a lack of education. I would try a reinterpretation of the sign in the light of this new idea.

Comment: I don't think, it has to be a lack of space, leading to omitted articles. For signs it is usually crucial to be able to comprehend them fast and omitted words may help you with that. Plus, it led to the German-sign-style dialect. Of course, this sign is a parody and also plays on this linguistic style.

Comment: I could imagine that even serious signs would use that style (something like "Wenn Alarm ertönt, Gebäude verlassen und Sammelpunkt aufsuchen" or "Rettungsweg freihalten")

Answer (score 5):

In this case it's wrong, you should use

> Ich war in **der** Schule. Ich gehe in **die** Schule.

Note that this is *not* the case for some countries, so saying

> Ich war in **_** Polen

is correct - there is no article for most countries, places or cities.

Comment: Switzerland is the famous exception (_Ich war in der Schweiz._).

Comment: As always; exceptions everywhere^^

Comment: Another bad one: ich fahre *in den* Irak, aber ich fahre *nach* Iran (according to ["Tagesschau"](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran#Landesname) ;-) )

Comment: Good thing we're ignoring dialects ("Gehst du am Wochenende auch auf Schalke?" ;-) )

Comment: Not to mention using synonyms for countries "Ich war in __den__ Staaten"

Comment: @musiKk: Not exactly a singular exception; countries whose names are feminine always go with an article (die Schweiz, die Mongolei ...).

Answer (score 4):

Although syntactically wrong, such incorrect usage has become popular in certain youth slang.

Here's a description of a language research project in Berlin, ["Bist du mit Auto oder gehst du Bahnhof?"](http://www.berliner-sprachforschung.de/plaintext/projekt/index.html).
They refer to this syntax construct as "Minimalkonstruktion", and suspect a Turkish-Arabic influence.

Similarly, in the third book of his series "Der Dativ ist dem Genitiv sein Tod", Bastian Sick quotes a German soccer player saying, "Ich habe Vertrag bis 2007."
Which is equally incorrect usage of course.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in this case it would be weird (read: wrong). It's always

> Ich war in der Schule.

and

> Ich gehe in die Schule.

Likewise for other places like town hall, hospital, swimming pool, church, etc.

Others have already indicated that it is different for many geographical places. But there are exceptions too:

- die Schweiz (Switzerland)
- the mountains: die Alpen, das Erzgebirge
- die Antarktis (Antarctica)

Answer (score 3):

Most people already pointed out, that it's wrong and provided some usage advice. I just wanted to give you some perspective with a correlation to Polish.
If you drop the article from German nouns, you're often losing two important bits of information:

- the **gender** of the noun
- the **case** of the noun

You could compare that to simply dropping suffixes from polish nouns. So that

> Chodzę do szkoły

would become

> Chodzę do szkoł

which is, I believe, plain wrong. Just be careful when transferring concepts between languages which have a significantly different grammatical structure.

Answer (score 1):

The phenomenon of the missing article in the German language is called **[Nullartikel](http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/lernen.php?menu_id=58)**.

In short, this is the case with substantives **without further determination**.

Such as

- Plural with indefinite article
- Abstracts
- Titels & Names
- Professions
- Substantives after size, weight and quantity information
- Not countable materials
- Nationalities
- Most countries
- Proverbs

See the link for examples.