# Benutzt man Artikel mit Toponymen?

Tags: preposition

Muss, darf, oder darf man nicht Artikel mit Toponymen benutzen?

> Ich wohne in der Maxvorstadt.
>
> Er geht in die Studentenstadt.
>
> Kommst du aus der Hamburg?

Comment: Siehe auch: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/271/articles-in-real-life

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Normalerweise **muss** man den Artikel weglassen:

- Ich lebe in Berlin.
- Ich fahre nach Bayern.
- Ich stamme aus Italien.

Es gibt allerdings auch Ausnahmen:

- Ich fliege in die USA.
- Ich komme aus dem Elsass.
- Ich verbringe meine Ferien in den Alpen.

---

**Städtenamen** werden **ohne Artikel** verwendet, außer wenn sie mit einem **Adjektiv** versehen sind, z.B.

> Ich habe das idyllische Meran besucht.

---

Ob ein **Ländername** mit oder ohne Artikel verwendet wird, hängt von seinem **Geschlecht** ab. Die meisten Länder sind in Deutsch **sächlich** (neutrum). Bei ihnen **fällt der Artikel weg**. Zum Beispiel bei Frankreich, Italien, Großbritannien.

Bei Ländernamen, die **weiblich** sind, **muss** der Artikel **verwendet werden**. Die Liste der Ländernamen mit Artikel ist allerdings sehr kurz:

- die Dominikanische Republik
- die Mongolei
- die Schweiz
- die Slowakei
- die Türkei
- die Ukraine
- die Zentralafrikanische Republik

Ländernamen mit **männlichem** Geschlecht gibt es auch viele und werden manchmal auch sächlich verwendet:

- der Irak
- der Iran
- der Jemen
- der Kongo
- der Libanon
- der Niger
- der Sudan
- der Tschad
- der Vatikan

Ländernamen im **Plural** werden ebenfalls **mit Artikel** verwendet:

- die Bahamas
- die Niederlande
- die Philippinen
- die Salomonen
- die Seychellen
- die USA (oder: die Vereinigten Staaten von Amerika)
- die Vereinigten Arabischen Emirate

Quelle: http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/0,1518,327185,00.html

---

Weitere geografische Namen:

- Inseln (Singular): **kein** Artikel ("Ich war auf Malta")
- Inseln (Plural): **mit** Artikel ("Ich ruderte um die Kanaren.")
- Gebirge, Seen, Flüsse: **mit** Artikel ("In den Anden ist es schön", "Im Bodensee liegt ein Schatz.", "Der Inn mündet in die Donau.")

Comment: Hm, das mit dem Neutrum kann ich nicht 1:1 glauben. Zwar "Ich war in England", aber doch wohl "Ich war im Saarland", nach meinem Gefühl. Ansonsten kann die Liste der "der"-Länder wohl um den Oman ergänzt werden (ups, wie ich bei Wikipedia lerne, gilt diese Ergänzung nur für Schweizer)

Answer (score 5):

Als Zusatz zu den anderen Antworten. Die meisten konzentrieren sich offenbar bei Toponymen vor allem auf Länder und Städte.

**Wälder, Berge, Gebirge und Gewässer** sind meist (immer?) mit Artikel

- der Schwarzwald
- das Erzgebirge, die Anden
- der Mt. Everest, die Zugspitze
- die Themse, der Po, der Aralsee, die Nordsee

Weiterhin habe ich das Gefühl, dass der Artikel oft benötigt wird, wenn der Hauptteil des Wortes kein Kunstname ist:

- die Maxvorstadt (die Stadt)
- *die* Vereinigten *Staaten*
- die Niederlande (die Lande)

**Straßen, Wege und Plätze**, die das entsprechende Wort als Teil haben, gehören ebenfalls dazu:

- die Hauptstraße, der Sachsendamm, die Herzallee
- der Werdauer Weg, die Sterngasse, das Barfußgässchen
- der Alexanderplatz

**Inseln** sind wie die meisten Städte und Länder. Möchte man jedoch betonen, dass es sich um eine Insel handelt, wird der Artikel immer verwendet:

- Helgoland, aber "die Insel Helgoland"

(Theoretisch gilt das natürlich für die anderen Orte auch, aber bei Inseln ist es imho gebräuchlicher als z. B. bei Städten: "die Stadt Hannover".)

**Inselgruppen** sind in der Regel im Plural und erhalten dadurch automatisch den Artikel "die":

- die Kanaren, die Azoren, die Seychellen

Was natürlich nicht bedeutet, dass es keine Ausnahmen en masse gibt:

- der Irak
- die Schweiz
- das Elsass
- das Suffix "land", sofern es im Sinne von Staat gebraucht wird: Deutschland, England, aber das Saarland, das Leipziger Land

Answer (score 3):

Toponyme haben **in der Regel keine** Artikel. Ob ein Toponym einen Artikel hat hängt von seinem *Geschlecht* ab. Die Regeln zur Bestimmung des Genus sind hier dieselben wie bei allen Substantiven.

Männliche Ländernamen:

- der Irak
- der Jemen
- der Kongo (auch Congo, eigtl. „die Demokratische Republik Kongo“)
- der Sudan (Umgangssprache, offiziell: „Die Republik Sudan“)
- der Senegal

Weibliche Ländernamen:

- die Schweiz
- die Niederlanden
- die Dominikanische Republik

In diesen Fällen muss der Artikel natürlich angepasst werden:

- Ich war im Kongo.
- Das BIP der Schweiz ist gestiegen.

Um den Genus zu bestimmen muss der Name in seine vollen Fassung betrachtet werden

> Die Schweizerische Eid**genossenschaft**
>
> Die Nieder**landen**
>
> Die Süd**stadt**

Comment: +1, aber der OP zeigt zwei interessante Ausnahmen (ein weiteres wäre z.b. "Die Südstadt"). Wo passen die rein?

Comment: Wie kann man wissen, ob ein Toponym Artikel hat, wenn es nur ein kleiner Stadtteil ist?

Comment: 'Die Südstadt' sollte jetzt klar sein.

Comment: "Das Saarland" ...?

Comment: @ladybug: „Das Saarland“ → „Das …Land“

Comment: @Stefano: Das Irland. Ich glaube, Saarland (und evtl. Niederlande) sind hier die Ausnahmen, nicht umgekehrt.

Comment: oder evtl. wenn es sich eher auf Regionen statt auf Staaten bezieht? Das Saarland, das Münsterland, das Sauerland vs. Irland, Deutschland, England? (Aber dann: "Und Pommerland ist abgebrannt"?) Bin mir da grad wirklich unsicher.

Comment: Typisch Deutsch: Sprache muss sich Regeln unterwerfen (hh1/2k ;-))

Comment: "volle Fassung" ist auch, Verzeihung, Blödsinn: "China", aber es heisst "Volksrepublik China".  Also sollte es, nach *der* Regel, "Die China" heissen.  Oh, und Kongo ist nur aua "Der Kongo", aber "Die ... Kongo".  Also was jetzt?  Seht ihr: es gibt keine 100%igen Regeln.

Comment: "Der Kongo" ist natürlich *der* Kongo weil damals, als *der* Kongo als Begriff eingeführt wurde, es noch keine demokratische Republik Kongo gab.  (War da Deutschland überhaupt schon Demokratie?  War doch noch im Kaiserreich, oder?)

Comment: Man muss sich natürlich nur dann den vollen Namen angucken, wenn man es mit einem nicht-sachlichen Toponym zu tun hat. :-) Das ist zugegebenermaßen rekursiv, hilft aber (zumindest in einigen Fällen) zu erkennen, warum jenes nun männlich oder weiblich ist.

Answer (score 0):

*Ursprünglich wurde nach Präpositionen gefragt, nicht nach Artikeln. **Diese** Frage beantworte ich hier.*

Das kommt auf den Fall an, in dem das Toponym verwendet wird. Als Akkusativ- oder Dativobjekt wird manchmal eine Präposition verwendet, jedoch kein Artikel.

Oder einfacher: Welche Frage beantwortet der Satz? Wo, woher, wohin? Dann verwende eine Präposition.

#### Nominativ

Beantwortet keine der Fragen.

- Das ist Berlin.
- Das Sauerland ist süß.

#### Dativ

- Der Müll gehört Hamburg. (beantwortet keine der Fragen, also keine Präposition)
- Der Müll kommt **aus** Hamburg. (woher?)

#### Akkusativ

- Wir finden Hamburg nicht. (beantwortet keine der Fragen)
- Wir fahren **um** Hamburg. (wohin?)

Answer (score 0):

Um nochmal auf die Beispielsätze zurückzukommen:

> Ich wohne in der Maxvorstadt.
>
> Er geht in die Studentenstadt.
>
> Kommst du aus der Hamburg?.

Die ersten beiden Sätze sind richtig, der dritte ist falsch. Da müsste es "Kommst du aus Hamburg" heißen.

Und wie die anderen schon sagten - da muss man beim Vokabellernen einfach aufpassen und mitlernen, ob man den Artikel braucht oder nicht. Gibt es aber m.W.n. im Französischen auch.

Comment: Es gibt viel zu viele Toponyme in der Welt zu lernen; gibt es keine Regel?

Comment: Leider nicht! Ein paar Faustregeln hat musiKk gepostet, aber die klappen nicht immer. Beispiel Endung "-land": "Saarland" wird immer mit Artikel verwendet, während "England" oder "Deutschland" ohne verwendet werden.

Comment: Ich glaube, Antworten hier werden oft in großen Ausnahmesammlungen enden. Langsam verstehe ich, warum Deutsch als schwierig angesehen wird. ;)

Comment: Ja, aber zum Glück haben wir nicht die einzige komplizierte Sprache. Lern mal französische Verben! ^^

Comment: Französisch hat auch mehr oder weniger willkürliche Geschlechter für Ländernamen (und alle übrigen Substantive)... Praktischerweise gibt es aber nur zwei Geschlechter, also nur 50% Chance, sich zu vertun ;) Leider hilft auch da nur Lernen. Dafür werden (glaube ich) bei Ländern immer Artikel vorangestellt. Immerhin.