# Regeln für bestimmte Artikel bei Staaten, Bundesländern und Bezirken

Tags: prefix, article, rule-of-thumb

### + Explanation (English)

I'm writing a piece of software. This software outputs a list. Each list item has meta data like the date, the author of and entry and as well the location.

The location can get build from `District`, `State` & `Country` and tells *where* exactly that item resides. Now the problem isn't the location, but determining the needed prefix:

## ? Question

What is the rule when "In/Im/In der" is used? Can I code that based on a rule, or do I have to use a list?

### + Erklärung (Deutsch)

Ich schreibe derzeit an einer Software. Diese gibt eine Liste aus. Jedes Listenelement verfügt über einen Satz Metadaten: Den Autor, das Datum, die Lokalität.

Die Lokalität kann aus mehreren Teilen bestehen: `Bezirk`, `Bundesland/Kanton/Distrikt`, `Staat`. Das Problem ist nun programmatisch herauszufinden, wann welcher bestimmte Artikel Verwendung findet:

## ? Question

Wie wird die Unterscheidung geregelt, wann "In/Im/In der" verwendet wird? Kann ich das programmatisch anwenden, oder muss ich eine Liste führen?

### Examples

Country/Staaten:

```
* In Deutschland
* In Österreich
* In Liechtenstein
* In Luxemburg
* In *der* Schweiz
```

State/Bundesland/Kanton/Distrikt:

```
* In Sachsen
* *Im* Burgenland
* In Hessen
* *Im* (Kanton) Zürich
* In Thüringen
```

District/Bezirk/Kanton:

```
* In Jennersdorf // Austria seems to only have `In` on a district level - case solved [1]
* *In der* Schmelz
* In Laupen
* *Im* Mersch (In der?)
* *Im* Oberland
```

---

I take the South-Tyrolean naming conventions of *Bezirksgemeinschaft* and *Talgemeinschaft*, as well as the Austrian convention of *Stadtbezirk*, *Katastralgemeinde*, *Stadtteil* and *Staturstadt* (and others) equal to `district`/`Bezirk`.

*Yeah, it's a little bit hard to determine the difference between Kanton/District in Luxembourg and Switzerland.*

[1] [List of Austrian districts](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Bezirke_und_Statutarst%C3%A4dte_in_%C3%96sterreich)

Comment: Bundesländer betreffend *in* (aber 
*im Bundesland*), wobei man auch *im Saarland* sagen könnte, wenn man sich nicht auf das Bundesland bezieht, so wie man auch *im Ruhrpott* oder *im Bergischen* sagt. In Österreich gibt es mind. eine Ausnahme: *In der Steiermark*. Bei Ländern gibt es auch klare Ausnahmen, die man in einer Liste erfassen kann. Aus dem Bauch heraus kann man Regeln erfassen, muss aber Ausnahmenlisten generieren.

Comment: @Em1 Sollte das nicht eine Antwort sein? Bzw. Kannst Du das Beispiel bitte etwas ausdehnen?

Comment: Ist nur ne Mutmaßung, habe keine Ahnung. Deswegen: Nein ;) - Welches Beispiel meinst du?

Comment: @kaiser Naja ich wusste ja nicht was genau du damit meintest. Ich dachte zuerst an Zürich, aber da ich nicht sicher war wollte ich lieber nichts editieren

Comment: @RoflcoptrException Dafür gibt's dann ja den "rollback" :)

Comment: @Em1 _Im Ruhrpott_, _Im Bergischen_, _In der Steiermark_. Punkt ist aber (und so gut kenne ich mich in groß D nicht aus), dass das nur offizielle Bezeichnungen sind. "Im mittleren Burgenland", "In der Oststeiermark", etc. gibt es also in meinem Fall nicht.

Comment: Weiß nicht, worauf du genau hinauswillst.

Comment: siehe auch http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/307/benutzt-man-artikel-mit-toponymen

Comment: @Em1: Was sonst könnte man beim Saarland sagen?

Comment: Side note: *Programmatisch* bedeutet *einem Konzept folgend/einem Grundsatz entsprechend* oder *richtungsweisend, zielsetzend*. Ich glaube, du willst aber was anderes sagen. Kenne aber kein Adjektiv, dass dort richtig ist. Man müsste den Satz umformen.

Comment: @Em1 Die Korrektur hat Sinn. Merci.

Comment: @Em1: *programmatisch* bezieht sich in der Frage darauf, dass die Entscheidung durch einen Algorithmus (durch ein Programm) getroffen werden soll. Genau das wird ja aber von *einem Konzept folgend* auch ausgedrückt. Der Duden listet sogar ausdrücklich *einem Programm entsprechend* als Bedeutung auf.

Answer (score 3):

Selbst wenn du aus dem Genus und der Stufe der Körperschaft eine Regel ableiten könntest, müsstest du diese Informationen trotzdem getrennt speichern.

Da ist es wohl einfacher, gleich die entsprechende Form in einer Liste zu speichern. Der Vorteil ist, dass du dann auch gleich Ausnahmen wie "im Kanton Zürich" ("im Zürich" alleine könnte missverständlich sein) berücksichtigen kannst.

Außerdem erleichterst du so eine spätere Übersetzung in andere Sprachen, die noch verrücktere Regeln haben können.

Answer (score 3):

Es kommt darauf an.

**Staaten:**

Sofern der Staat vom Geschlecht neutrum ist, kommt immer "In" davor. (In Deutschland, In Österreich)

Wenn das Geschlecht des Staates allerdings nicht neutral ist, wird der Artikel, bezogen auf den Kasus verwendet (Bspw. "In der Schweiz").

**Bundesland:**

Normalerweise sind Bundesländer ebenfalls neutral. In deinen Beispielen gibt es aber Ausnahmen:

```
Im Burgenland
```

Das rührt daher, dass der Artikel dem (im = in dem) von dem Teilwort "land" stammt. 
Ähnlich bei dem nächsten Beispiel:

```
Im (Kanton) Zürich
```

Wie du bereits bemerkt hast, würde man das Wort *Kanton* dazwischenlegen, wodurch sich der Artikel nicht mehr auf *Zürich* bezieht, sondern auf *Kanton*.

**Bezirk:**

Hier verhält es sich wie beim Bundesland. Deine Beispiele sind allerdings gemischt:

*Die Schmelz* ist eine Gemeinde, **die** Gemeinde. Deshalb wird auch *In der Schmelz* gesagt, da sich der Artikel auf *Gemeinde* bezieht:

```
In der (Gemeinde) Schmelz
```

Gleiches mit *Mersch*:

```
In dem (Kanton) Mersch
```

(Vgl. Zürich)

In Laupen bezieht sich übrigens auch auf *In (der Gemeinde) Laupen*, den Artikel hinzuzufügen wäre 100% korrekt.

Bei *Im Oberland* zeigt der Artikel wieder auf das "-land" in Oberland, weshalb dort, abhängig vom Kasus, der Artikel nur "Land" beschreibt.

**Zusammenfassung der letzten Kategorie:**

- *In Jennersdorf* - Jennersdorf ist eine Stadt; daher nur *In*
- *In der Schmelz* - Die Schmelz ist eine Gemeinde; daher *Die Schmelz*. Nur *Schmelz* wäre ebenfalls korrekt (und würde ich bevorzugen).
- *In Laupen* - Siehe Schmelz. Auch hier *könnte* man *In der Laupen* sagen, aber das klingt nur noch komischer als *die Schmelz* ;). Beides ist einfach ohne feste Regel, nach Klang beurteilt.
- *Im Mersch* - Der Artikel ist hier *dem*, da er sich auf *das Kanton* bezieht (Dativ!).
- *Im Oberland* - Der Artikel ist hier *dem*, da er sich das *Das Land* bezieht (ebenfalls Dativ!).

Um die Artikel herauszufinden, musst du sowohl den Fall, als auch das eigentliche Wort herausfinden, auf das sich der Artikel bezieht.

Comment: +1 Kurz angemerkt: Da ich derzeit eben nur die Daten begutachten kann, die mir schon ausgegeben werden, musste ich um Beispiele ergänzen. Als Österreicher kenne ich natürlich nicht alles in Deutschland, der Schweiz, Lichtenstein, etc. Falls da etwas falsch war, bitte einfach ignorieren, bzw. durch ein anderes (deutlicheres) Beispiel ergänzen.