# Richtungen und Ziele: Wir fahren "nach / in / zu / an" [Artikel] XYZ?

Tags: word-usage

Ich bin Muttersprachler und habe keine Probleme das richtige Wort zu finden, aber wie bringe ich einem Fremdsprachler das bei:

- Wir fahren **zu** euch.
- Wir fahren **zur** Schule.
- Wir fahren **zum** Fussbalspiel.
- Wir fahren **zu** Oma.
- Wir fahren **nach** Hause.

Okay, halte dich fest:

- Wir fahren **nach** Deutschland.
- Wir fahren **nach** Oesterreich.
- Wir fahren **in die** Schweiz.
- Wir fahren **in** die Berge.
- Wir fahren **in** ein fremdes Land.
- Wir fahren **in** eine interessante Region.
- Wir fahren **zu** einer Sehenswuerdigkeit.
- Wir fahren **in** den Urlaub
- Wir fahren **an** den Strand.

Es wird besser:

- Wir fahren **nach** westen
- Wir fahren **in** den Westen
- Wir fahren **nach** Links
- Wir fahren **an** die linke Seite
- Wir fahren **zur** linken Seite

Vereinigten Staaten:

- Wir fahren **nach** Texas
- Wir fahren **nach** Michigan
- Wir fahren **nach** Kalifornien
- Wir fahren **nach** Chicago
- Wir fahren **nach** New York
- Wir fahren **nach** Los Angeles

Sieht so aus als geht alles was einen Namen hat mit nach, aber dann passiert das:

- Wir fahren **in** die USA.
- Wir fahren **in** die Great Plains
- Wir fahren **in** den Mittleren Westen
- Wir fahren **an** die Westkueste
- Wir fahren **an** die Ostkueste

Kontinente:

- Wir fahren **nach** Amerkia
- Wir fahren **nach** Australien
- Wir fahren **nach** Afrika
- Wir fahren **nach** Europa
- Wir fahren **nach** Asien
- Wir fahren **an** den Nordpol

okay hier bin ich selber nicht sicher:

- Wir fahren **an** die Antarktis
- Wir fahren **in** die Antarktis

*Wann benutzt man **nach**, wann **zu**, wann **in**, wann **an**?!*

*Und noch dazu woher weiss ich ob ich den Artikel verwende oder nicht?*

Comment: Nordpol ist aber ein komischer Kontinent!

Comment: Sorry, gehoert wohl eher unter Staedte...

Comment: _Nordpol_: eher zu Punkten und Linien (mit den Küsten). _Antarktis_: klar *in*.

Comment: Vgl. http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/307, http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2540

Comment: Vll. kann auch *auf Kuba* (oder andere Insel) hinzugefügt werden.

Comment: Bei Inselstaaten ist die Präposition für „vor Ort sein“ auch ganz interessant: `Wir waren im Urlaub auf Malta.` vs. `Wir waren im Urlaub in Malta.` Das passiert bei allen Inselstaaten außer Großbritannien, weil das irgendwie nicht als Insel wahrgenommen wird.

Comment: Und was ist mit _zur Antarktis_ und _nach Antarktis_ ?

Comment: »Zur Antarktis« ginge schon, aber dann kommt man gefühlt nicht so ganz an, sondern schippert mit dem Boot vor der Küste umher. »Nach Antarktis« geht nicht, weil es *die Antarktis* heißt.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Für Namen, die keinen Artikel haben, benutzt man `nach`:

> Nach Texas, nach Amerika, nach Deutschland, nach Berlin

Namen, die einen Artikel haben, werden wie andere Bezeichnungen behandelt.

Für geographische Gebiete (denen man also eine Flächenausdehnung zuspricht), benutzt man `in`:

> in die Berge, in die USA, in die Antarktis, in *den* Westen, in ein fremdes Land

Für geographische Punkte und Linien (denen man also keine Flächenausdehnung zuspricht), benutzt man `an` oder `zu`:

> an den Nordpol, an die Küste, an den Strand, ans Dreiländereck
>
> zum Nordpol, zur Küste, zum Strand, zum Dreiländereck

Für (geographische) Richtungsangaben benutzt man `nach`:

> nach links, nach vorne, nach *westen*

Für geographische Orte, für die man sich eine Aufwärtsbewegung vorstellt, um dorthinzugelangen, benutzt man `auf`

> auf die Insel, auf die Weihnachtsinsel, auf die Kanaren
>
> auf den Berg, auf den Mt. Everest

Für Orte, denen man keine geographsiche Größenordnung zuspricht, verwendet man `zu`

> zur Schule, zum Fußballspiel, zur Seite, zum Arzt, zu mir oder zu dir, zu Oma

Ausnahmen

> nach Hause
>
> zur Seite (wenn man das als Richtungsangabe interpretiert)
>
> verschiedene Dialekte (Mein thüringer Opa sagte immer: „Geh mal bei Oma!“)

Ich erhebe keinen Anspruch auf Vollständigkeit.

Comment: Da es [(der) Westen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Westen) ist, wird er offenbar nicht wie eine Richtung, sondern eher wie ein Ort ohne Artikel behandelt: »Wir fahren nach Westen.«. »nach westen« ist falsch.