# Confusion to say "to" in German about some special countries

Tags: preposition

Do we use *nach* always for all destinations among countries, except for Switzerland and Turkey (in die Schweiz, in die Türkei)?
Is there any other exception where we don’t use *nach* with the sense of *to*?

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8479/richtungen-und-ziele-wir-fahren-nach-in-zu-an-artikel-xyz

Comment: thanks @c.p. for that versatile reference, but I mean a precise answer only for " nach" in the sense of "toward".

Comment: The linked question is in German, this one is in English. Hence, they are not duplicates (albeit related).

Comment: Neither means *toward*.

Comment: *Toward* sagt man im Deutschen gar nicht.

Comment: Well, I am not a native English speaker, but to me, *toward* and *to* mean different things.

Comment: Additionally, you sometimes could say "Wir fahren gen Osten [hin]" ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the place name has an article, you use *in* or *zu*. If not, *nach*. It isn't limited to countries. The real question has to be what's the rule about place names and articles. Hint: there isn't one, but many, many and for countries, you have to learn them one by one.

Places used with an article:

> Wir fahren in die Niederlande.
>
> Ich fahre in den Harz.
>
> Sie geht ins Museum.
>
> Ich fahre zum Supermarkt.
>
> Ich gehe in den Supermarkt.

Places used without an article:

> Wir fahren nach Dänemark.
>
> Ich fahre nach Berlin.
>
> Sie geht nach oben.

Comment: The rule is of course that you use an article unless the country is neuter, but that only shifts the problem.

Comment: Aber "auf die Falklandinseln", "auf das Muroroaatoll".

Comment: @userunknown, good point, I was thinking of countries only.

Comment: In die Dominikanische Republik, in die Bundesrepublik Deutschland, in die BRD, in die DDR, in die ... Republik ganz allgemein, auf die ...insel(n), in den Kongo, ...