# When do you use nach versus zu versus in?

Tags: word-choice, preposition

> **This question also has an answer here (in German):**
>   *http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8479*

I would like to say, "Today I went to Candy & Chocolates," where Candy & Chocolates is the name of a candy store in my neighborhood.

I think it would be something like **Ich bin nach Candy & Chocolates gegangen**, but I'm not sure which preposition to use: nach, zu, or in.

In sentences with a verb of motion like *gehen*, how do you decide on the preposition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Richtungen und Ziele: Wir fahren "nach / in / zu / an" \[Artikel\] XYZ?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8479/richtungen-und-ziele-wir-fahren-nach-in-zu-an-artikel-xyz)

Comment: @Eller and others thinking about close-voting: We found an agreement via [Meta] (I don't have the link at hand) that questions in different languages are not treated as *duplicates*, but merely cross-linked.

Answer (score 2):

***This is only a translation of the answer originally posted by @toscho in the aforementioned link (http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8479) within the question!***

***I do not take any credits for the answer itself!***

*If you find any gramatical errors feel free to edit. :-)*

For names that have any article, use `nach` as followed:

> Nach Texas, nach Amerika, nach Deutschland, nach Berlin
>
> 'Ich wollte schon immer mal **nach Texas**.' 'Wir fliegen **nach Amerika**.' 'Wir wandern **nach Deutschland** aus.' 'Wir fahren am Wochenende **nach Berlin** zu einer Ausstellung.'

Names that have any article will be handled as other designations.

For geographical regions (ascribing a surface area) use `in`:

> in die Berge, in die USA, in die Antarktis, in *den* Westen, in ein fremdes Land
>
> 'Wir werden **in die Berge** fahren.' 'Wir fliegen **in die USA**.' 'Ich fahre im Urlaub **in die Antarktis** und sehe mir die Eisberge an.' 'Wir flohen damals aus der DDR **in den Westen**.' 'Ich wollte **in ein fremdes Land** reisen und eine andere Kultur kennen lernen.'

For geographical points and latitudes/longitudes (not ascribing a surface area) use `an(s)` or `zu(m/r)`:

> an den Nordpol, an die Küste, an den Strand, ans Dreiländereck
>   zum Nordpol, zur Küste, zum Strand, zum Dreiländereck
>
> 'Ich reise **an den/zum** Nordpol!' 'Wir fahren zum Urlaub **an die/zur** Küste.' 'Lass uns **an den/zum** Strand gehen.' 'Wir wollten **ans/zum Dreiländereck**.'

For (geographical and spatial) directions use `nach`:

> nach links, nach vorne, nach *westen*, nach unten, nach oben
>
> 'Gehen Sie an der Kreuzung **nach links**, ...' 'Mussten wir vorhin nicht **nach rechts** abbiegen?' 'Viele Fachkräfte sind aus der DDR **nach westen gegangen**.' 'Geh bitte **nach unten** in den Keller und hole eine Dose Pfirsiche.' 'Ich muss noch einmal **nach oben** gehen, ich habe meinen Schlüssel vergessen.'

If you travel to some geographical locations it can be set to a similarity as a vertical movement.
To describe such a travel use `auf`:

> auf die Insel, auf die Weihnachtsinsel, auf die Kanaren
>   auf den Berg, auf den Mt. Everest
>
> 'Wir fahren im Sommer immer **auf die Insel** Sylt.' 'Ich war im Urlaub **auf der Weihnachtsinsel** gewesen.' 'Wir **fliegen auf** die Kanaren.' 'Wir steigen **auf den Berg**.'

For non-geographical locations use `zu`:

> zur Schule, zum Fußballspiel, zur Seite, zum Arzt, zu mir oder zu dir, zu Oma
>   'Ich muss jeden Tag **zur Schule** gehen.' 'Am Wochenende gingen wir **zum Fußballspiel**.' 'Gehe mal bitte **zur Seite**, ich muss an den Schrank!' 'Ich fühle mich heute nicht gut, ich muss **zum Arzt** gehen.' 'Gehen wir heute **zu dir oder zu mir**?' 'Möchtest du heute **zu Oma** fahren?'

There are exceptions (what a surprise ;-) ), but there is one which you will find every day:

> nach Hause (going home)

***This is only a translation of the answer originally posted by @toscho in the aforementioned link (http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8479) within the question!***

***I do not take any credits for the answer itself!***

*If you find any gramatical errors feel free to edit. :-)*

Answer (score 1):

„zu“ if it is a store. 
„nach“ would be for a place (city, region, country)

Comment: „Nach“ wird regional (z. B. in NRW) auch verwendet, um zu beschreiben, dass man zu einem Geschäft geht: Er geht nach Rewe, einkaufen.

Comment: Was dann aber dialektisch bedingt ist, aber nicht der Regel entspricht. Für den Muttersprachler sicherlich hinnehmbar, aber hilft nicht denen, die die Sprache lernen wollen.

Comment: @HappySPUser für mich als Muttersprachler aus einer anderen Region ist "nach Rewe gehen" oder "bei ALDI gehen" ziemlich gruselig. <schauder>

Comment: @Stephie Für mich als Muttersprachler klingt es auch grauenvoll. Nichtsdestotrotz, ich kenne viele aus der Bildungsschicht, die so sprechen.
Ich wollte es auch bloß erwähnt haben. Bin auch beileibe kein Fan von Bastian Sick, aber hier thematisiert er die Präpositionen: http://www.spiegel.de/lebenundlernen/schule/zwiebelfibel-ich-geh-nach-aldi-a-398751.html

Comment: Ich geh aufn Bus und fahr bei mein Omma.