# Wann heißt es „in <Staatsname>“ und wann „im <Staatsname>“?

Tags: preposition, place-name

Mir ist heute aufgefallen, dass *in* und *im* im Gebrauch mit Ländernamen keiner erkennbaren grammatikalischen Regel folgen.

Zum Beispiel sagt man *in Deutschland, in Russland* und *in Somalia*, aber auch *im Irak, im Sudan* und *im Kongo*.

Wie kommt dies zustande?

Comment: Zumindest verwandte [Frage](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/307/1696), wenn nicht Duplikat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Das hängt davon ab, wie der Staat als ganzes benutzt wird. Manche Staaten haben einen Artikel und sind damit einhergehend meistens keine Neutra. Die überwiegende Mehrzahl der Staaten der Erde wird jedoch artikellos verwendet – und diese sind stets Neutra.

Alles folgende ist die übliche deutsche Grammatik. Um den Zustand *in einem Ort* zu beschreiben, wird die Präposition *in* mit Dativ verwendet. Wo ein Staatsname einen Artikel besitzt, wird dieser entsprechend mitdekliniert. Und die Kombination *in dem* wird systematisch zu *im* verkürzt.

Beispiele:

- Der Kongo → im Kongo
- Die Mongolei → in der Mongolei
- Kanada (artikellos also Neutrum) → in Kanada (verbleibt artikellos)
- Das schöne Kanada (mit Attribut erscheint der Artikel) → im schönen Kanada
- Die Niederlande → in den Niederlanden.

Analog dazu werden Akkusativformen benötigt, wenn es um die Bewegung in einen Staat hinein geht. Dann heißt es *in den Kongo, in die Mongolei, in das schöne Kanada* oder *in die Niederlande.* Wird bei Kanada das Attribut weggelassen, muss man allerdings *nach* sagen, um Missverständnisse zu vermeiden.

Obiges gilt übrigens nicht nur für Staatsnamen sondern auch für Regionen und sonstige Gebiete. Zum Beispiel *im Landkreis* (maskulin), *in der Finnmark* (feminin) *im Saarland* (Neutrum), *in den Alpen* (Plural)

Answer (score 2):

- Neutrum: (das) Russland, in Russland
- Maskulinum: der Sudan, im Sudan
- Femininum: die Schweiz, in der Schweiz