# In der VAE oder in den VAE?

Tags: article, proper-noun, declension

Ich bin nicht sicher, ob man auf Deutsch "in der" oder "in den" vor VAE schreibt.

Ich dachte, dass es Plural Dativ ist, und dass man "den" schreiben soll, aber danach habe ich gegoogled und ähnliche Ergebnisse für "[der](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk01SK3sFCa1TQjfqfK1ybPeYDGM-OA%3A1611156999878&ei=B04IYL6WNYr1kwW8kY3wBw&q=%22in%20der%20VAE%22&oq=%22in%20der%20VAE%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIGCAAQChAeMgYIABAIEB4yBggAEAgQHjIGCAAQCBAeMgYIABAIEB4yBggAEAgQHjoECCMQJzoFCAAQywE6BAgAEB46BggAEAUQHjoHCCMQsAIQJzoECAAQEzoKCAAQCBAHEB4QEzoICAAQBxAKEB46CAgAEAgQBxAeUMsSWK0VYP0XaABwAHgAgAF9iAGLBJIBAzMuMpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwj-tZ7F66ruAhWK-qQKHbxIA34Q4dUDCAw&uact=5)" (491 000) und "[den](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk03AKeaxsBp3vRm7wFRxEIM6uuv-8g%3A1611156976677&ei=8E0IYPXhKIKbkgXKuqjoCA&q=%22in%20den%20VAE%22&oq=%22in%20den%20VAE%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIGCAAQDRAeOgQIIxAnOgIIADoHCCMQ6gIQJzoJCCMQ6gIQJxATOggIABDHARCvAToICAAQxwEQowI6BAgAEEM6AgguOgUIABDLAToLCAAQxwEQrwEQywE6BQguEMsBOgQIABATOggIABAWEB4QEzoHCCEQChCgAToFCCEQoAFQwm1Yn5ABYKWTAWgDcAB4AIABsgGIAcEPkgEEMS4xNZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXqwAQrAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwj1mZa666ruAhWCjaQKHUodCo0Q4dUDCAw&uact=5)" (384 000) gefunden.

Ich verstehe, dass "der" in vielen Fällen Genitiv meint, aber es gibt auch viele Fälle, wenn dort eigentlich Dativ steht. Wie soll ich entscheiden?

Comment: Denk Dir die VAE durch die bekannteren USA ersetzt - da dieselbe unterliegende Struktur vorliegt, gilt dieselbe Regel (und derselbe Umstand, dass manche Schreiber sie achtlos verletzen).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ich bekomme deutlich mehr Treffer für »in den VAE« als für »in der VAE«, aber selbt die Wikipedia-Autoren scheinen sich da nicht einig zu sein.

Wenn Du davon ausgehst, dass »die Vereinigten Arabischen Emirate« (im Nominativ Plural) der richtige Name des Landes ist, dann ist

> in den VAE

die einzig richtige Form.

Das ist auch die Form die z. B. das [Auswärtige Amt](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/aussenpolitik/laender/vereinigtearabischeemirate-node/vereinigtearabischeemiratesicherheit/202332) verwendet.

Comment: Ein Argument für _in den VAE_ scheint mir die Analogie zu _in den USA_ zu sein.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach ich war sicher, dass es genauso wie "in den USA" funktioniert, danach habe ich gegoogled und sich noch mehr verwirrt.

Comment: @P.Vowk Texte im Internet können auch von Menschen erstellt werden, die die deutsche Sprache nicht korrekt beherrschen. Suchmaschinenfunde für bestimmte Formen sind kein Beweis für deren Richtigkeit.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Die Analogie beschränkt sich darauf, den Landesnamen als Plural zu interpretieren, wo das Genus des Substantivs (Staat: mask. != Emirat: neutrum) keine Auswirkung hat. Da gibt es noch ein paar weitere, siehe [hier](https://deutschtraining.org/deutsche-grammatik/artikel/laender-mit-artikel/).

Comment: @guidot Die Analogie beinhaltet auch noch, dass es sich sowohl bei USA als auch VAE um Abkürzungen handelt. Aber ja, vielleicht gibt es noch weitere Beispiele. Das würde die Analogie ja nicht schwächer, sondern stärker machen, oder?

Answer (score 6):

Wenn eine Abkürzung für eine Wortgruppe steht – wie z.B. *VAE* für *Vereinigte Arabische Emirate* –, dann übernimmt die Abkürzung das Genus des semantischen Kerns (hier: *das Emirat*).

Wenn das Kurzwort die Verkürzung eines einzelnen Wortes darstellt, kann das Geschlecht sich unterscheiden (z.B. *das Foto* von *die Fotografie*).

Abkürzungen, die zu Namen geworden sind, erhalten ihr grammatisches Geschlecht dagegen nach den Regeln von Namen. Beispielsweise ist *der BMW* grammatisch männlich, wie viele Automobile (*der Mercedes*, *der Fiat*, *der Jeep* usw.), weil die Abkürzung in dieser Verwendung die Bedeutung der Wortgruppe verloren hat, für die sie einst stand.

---

*Quelle*

- Balnat,  Vincent  (2011): Kurzwortbildung  im  Gegenwartsdeutsch  (Germanistische
  Linguistik Monographien, 26). Hildesheim: Olms. S. 175.
- Engel, Julia (2020): Genus bei Namen. http://mediawiki.ids-mannheim.de/VarGra/index.php/Genus_bei_Namen

Comment: Zustimmung, was das Genus betrifft; *United Kingdom* bekommt aber auch abgekürzt zu UK keinen Artikel.

Comment: @guidot Duden meint "das UK", s. https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/UK. Mir begegnet die Abkürzung im Deutschen aber nicht. Hab noch nie gehört, dass jemand "jukäi" sagt oder "uhkah". Du? Die meisten meiner Bekannten sagen "England", wenn sie das Vereinigte Königreich meinen, manche auch "Vereinigtes Königreich", wenn sie genau sein wollen.

Comment: Die Ente und die Corvette sind Autos, die nicht männlich sind.

Answer (score 1):

Zusammengefasst spielen drei Faktoren eine Rolle:

- Genus (da gibt es schon eine ähnliche Frage zu Ländernamen [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34993/wann-hei%C3%9Ft-es-in-staatsname-und-wann-im-staatsname))
- Numerus (Singular oder Plural)
- wird der Landesname überhaupt mit Artikel verwendet (das ist die Ausnahme).

Zu den meisten Aspekten gibt [Deutschtraining](https://deutschtraining.org/deutsche-grammatik/artikel/laender-mit-artikel/) Auskunft.

Wir habe es bei *Emirate* mit Neutrum Plural zu tun, und die vielen Treffer aus der Frage legen nahe, dass bei VAE der Artikel auch verwendet wird.

Answer (score 0):

Es sind die Vereinigten Arabischen Emirate, also mehrere Emirate, also Plural.

Hier sind einige zum Teil gekürzte Beispielsätze aus dem Wikipedia-Artikel über die VAE:

> Eine starke Verbesserung der Beziehungen zwischen Saudi-Arabien und **den VAE** trat ein, als König Faisal an die Macht gekommen war.
>
> Am 11. Februar 1972 trat Ra’s al-Chaima als siebtes und letztes Emirat der ehemaligen Trucial States **den VAE** bei.
>
> Politikwissenschaftlich handelt es sich bei **den VAE** somit um eine bundesstaatlich organisierte konstitutionelle Monarchie.
>
> Der FNC spielt eine wichtige Rolle in der Konsolidierung der Schura in **den VAE.**
>
> Aus diesem Grund war eine Brücke über das Meer zwischen **den VAE** und Katar im Gespräch.

---

**Länder und Regionen, die im Plural verwendet werden:**

- die Bahamas (Inselgruppe)

  > Auf **den Bahamas** leben heute etwa 300.000 Menschen.
- die Faröer (Inselgruppe)

  > Die Färinger betrachten sich als Nachkommen von Wikingern auf **den Färöern.**
- die Niederlande

  > ... da es in **den Niederlanden** kein Gebirge und nur wenige Erhöhungen gibt.
- die Philippinen

  > Die durchschnittliche Jahrestemperatur auf **den Philippinen** beträgt 26,5°C.
- die Vereinigten Arabischen Emirate (die VAE)

  > In den 1970er Jahren wurde die Grenze zwischen Saudi-Arabien und **den VAE** verbindlich festgelegt.
- die Vereinigten Staaten von Amerika (die USA)

  > 2013 bezogen in **den USA** 47 Millionen Menschen staatliche Lebensmittelmarken.