# In/Im [City Name]

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, article, proper-noun

I would like to write this sentence: What happened in New York in 2001.09.11.
Which one of the following is the correct one?

> Was ist am 11. September 2001 ***in*** New York passiert?
> Was ist am 11. September 2001 ***im*** New York passiert?

I can't find anything online. I mean I can find things but they are like: **in** Berlin. End of sentence. I don't know if that *in* will change and become *im* in my example sentence.

Comment: According to the SE guidelines, questions should include the results of the research done so far. Why do you think it could be the one or the other? I think many grammar pages available online, let alone grammar books, should cover the topic *city/proper names and articles*.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus I mean I can find things but they are like: in Berlin. End of sentence. I don't know if that **in** will change and become **im** in my example sentence.

Comment: I added your comments into the question. Please explain why you think *in* could change to *im* in your sentence, so we can reopen your question.

Comment: @Olafant I don't know. I'm not German. That is why I'm asking. I sometimes see **in** as **in dem** and I don't know if this is the case here. If I'm correct, that is the Dativ form and I don't know if is Dativ in this case or not.

Comment: Merely checking for correctness is not the purpose of the site. For clear-cut cases like this, Google Translate gives the correct answer. Or a dictionary: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/in_innen_innerhalb has *lebt in Berlin*. If it is about more than correctness, the question should reflect that; for instance, by using terms such as *definite article*, *preposition*, *names of cities* to formulate a problem.

Comment: I vote to reopen this question because it's legitimate and not trivial. Why is it *»**in** Albanien«* but *»**im** Kosovo«?* Why *»**in** Kenia«* but *»**im** Kongo«?* Why *»**in** Gambia«* but *»**im** Senegal«?*

Comment: Related German [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/34993/1696) concerning **country** names. I fail to recognize a convincing argument for re-open this question but would re-consider if someone is able to come up with a non-neuter town name.

Comment: I think too that we shouldn't reopen it, but @guidot, can you place a "This is a duplicate of [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/34993/1696)" thing?

Comment: @guidot Just as an historical anecdote: *Den Haag* used to be also called *Der Haag* in German, and, according to Wikipedia:  "man tagte **im** Haag". But nowadays, no such thing seem to exist.

Comment: PS: City names with gender/articles don't seem to go well with the German language system: there is no German city with an article even if it could be considered sensible, cf. *Bremerhaven* vs. the French city of *Le Havre*, and unlike, e.g., in French (Le Caire), the article of *Cairo* (al-Qahira) wasn't adopted.

Comment: @guidot I have removed your note about the unrelated German question. This one is about cities, not countries. And since when do we write notes about related questions into the question and not in a comment? The link wasn't working btw.

Comment: @Olafant: While I agree (see my comment above), it is a direct response to the reopen argumentation of Hubert and directly follows the proposal of original question poster, see his comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### in ↔︎ im

The word *»im«* is a contraction of the preposition *»in«* and the article *»dem«.* So, the difference between *»in«* and *»im«* is the presence of an article, and this is also the reason why *»im«* works only in dative case, only in singular, only for masculine and neuter nouns, and only if you talk about a certain thing ("definite" i.e. not about just any thing), because *»dem«* is the definite dative singular article for masculine and neuter nouns.

- dative singular masculine definite

  > Die Leute sind **im** Wald. = Die Leute sind **in dem** Wald.
- dative singular neuter definite

  > Die Leute sind **im** Haus. = Die Leute sind **in dem** Haus.
- **accusative** singular masculine definite

  > Die Leute fahren **in den** Wald.
- dative **plural** definite

  > Die Leute sind **in den** Wäldern.
- dative singular **feminine** definite

  > Die Leute sind **in der** Hütte.
- dative singular masculine **indefinite**

  > Die Leute sind **in einem** Wald.

So your question boils down to: Do I have to use *»New York«* with or without an article?

---

### Articles of geographic names

Names of places where no or just a few people live are used with an article. This can be seas, rivers, lakes, forests, mountains etc.:

> Viele Flüchtlinge ertrinken jedes Jahr **im** Mittelmeer.
> Lange gab es keine Lachse **im** Rhein.
> Reichenau ist die größte Insel **im** Bodensee.
> Machen Sie Urlaub **im** Wienerwald!
> **Im** Dachstein liegt eine große Eishöhle.

But places where people live are used without an article. Such places can be anything from the smallest village up to continents.

> **In** Trabersdorf leben nur 15 Menschen, es ist das kleinste Dorf **in** Österreich.
> **In** Asien leben 4,46 Milliarden Menschen, das sind rund 60% der Weltbevölkerung.

And for this reason also all names of cities are used without an article:

> Im Jahr 1910 lebten mehr Menschen **in** Wien als **in** Berlin.
> Der Kreml steht **in** Moskau.
> Manhattan liegt **in** New York.

So, the answer to your question is:

> *correct:* Was ist am 11. September 2001 **in** New York passiert?
> *wrong:* <del>Was ist am 11. September 2001 **im** New York passiert?</del>

---

### Exceptions

Maybe you don't want to talk about just New York, but about a specific version of New York. The city is constantly changing, and you might want to talk about **the** New York of 1930. So, it's a very specific version of New York, and this requires a definite article. And because in German all cities are grammatically neuter, you have to use the article *»dem«* in dative case, which merges with *»in«* to *»im«:*

> **Im** New York der frühen 1930er-Jahre war es verboten, Alkohol herzustellen.
> **Im** Wien des Jahres 1910 lebten mehr als 2 Millionen Menschen.

You also turn a geographic place into a special version of it (at least in a grammatical manner) by adding any other attributes:

> **Im** schönen Frankreich gibt es viel zu sehen.
> **Im** weit entfernten Sidney zieht die Sonne im Norden über den Himmel.
> **Im** Amerika, das man im Film sieht, gibt es fliegende Autos.

Another class of exceptions are some countries that are always used with an article:

> Ich war noch niemals **im** Senegal.
> Bagdad liegt **im** Irak.

There is [a similar question in German language](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/307/benutzt-man-artikel-mit-toponymen), and in the answers you will find lists of countries that are used with an article together with their grammatical genders.

Comment: Thank you very much for you super-detailed explanation! Everything is clear now.

Comment: "But places where people live are used without an article." Verrat das nicht den Leuten, die in der Türkei wohnen, oder im Irak, oder in den USA, oder in der Tschechischen Republik, ... :-)

Comment: @mhchem: Genau dieses Thema habe ich am Ende meiner Antwort behandelt (beginnend mit »Another class of exceptions«), unter anderem mit der Erwähnung des von dir genannten Irak. Ich habe dort auch zu einer anderen Frage verlinkt, in der dieses Thema intensiver beleuchtet wird.

Comment: I am pretty sure this wasn't there yesterday. Well, I guess I didn't notice. Thanks for complete and exaustive answer.

Comment: @mhchem: Here is the edit history: https://german.stackexchange.com/posts/64763/revisions You will see, that the part about countries that always need an article was there already in the very first version of my answer, and you will also see that the last edit was made at *»Apr 21 at 8:52«*, i.e. more than a week before your comment.