# Hat die Verwendung des bestimmten Artikels in "die Ukraine" eine politische Konnotation?

Tags: idiom, article, proper-noun, connotation

Auf Englisch gibt es bei der Wahl zwischen "Ukraine" und "the Ukraine" politische Konnotationen.  Zum Beispiel, siehe [dieses Artikel auf *the conversation*](https://theconversation.com/its-ukraine-not-the-ukraine-heres-why-178748) (auf Englisch). Auf Englisch ist es mittlerweile üblich um über "Ukraine" statt "the Ukraine" zu sprechen und schreiben, weil "the Ukraine" interpretiert wird, als ob es sich um eine Region handelt statt über ein unabhängiges Land.

Mir fällt auf, dass auf Deutsch über "die Ukraine" gesprochen und geschrieben wird, während es bei Polen, Ungarn, Tschechien, Frankreich, Russland, oder Dänemark kein Artikel gibt.  Gilt hier auch, dass es eine politische Konnotation gibt bei der Wahl zwischen "Ukraine" und "der Ukraine", oder kann man das auf Deutsch so nicht richtig sagen?

Comment: https://deutschtraining.org/deutsche-grammatik/artikel/laender-mit-artikel/

Comment: Vegleichbare Frage auf englisch: *Russian has no definite article, and as far as I know, the Russian name for (the) Ukraine has not changed since the country’s independence* https://english.stackexchange.com/a/155832/21489

Comment: Gegenmeinung: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/58742/21489

Comment: [Use of the definite article in "the Ukraine"](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/23232/use-of-the-definite-article-in-the-ukraine)

Comment: @BernhardDöbler auf Russisch gibt es die Frage [*"На Украину" oder "в Украину"*](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/46568), was, wenn ich es richtig verstehe, auch geopolitische Implikationen hat.

Comment: "Die[,] Ukraine" hat auf Englisch noch viel schlechtere Konnotationen als "the Ukraine"…

Comment: Verwandte [Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/307/1696).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Länderbezeichnungen sind uneinheitlich. In den meisten Fällen wird kein Artikel vorangestellt, aber es gibt

- die Ukraine
- die Schweiz
- die Slowakei
- die Türkei
- die Mongolei
- der Iran
- der Irak

Eine politische Konnotation ist nicht gegeben. Eine vollständige Liste gibt es [hier](https://deutschtraining.org/deutsche-grammatik/artikel/laender-mit-artikel/).

Weitere Länder, bei denen ein Artikel verwendet wird, sind

- die Niederlande
- die USA / die Vereinigten Staaten
- die UdSSR / die Sowjetunion
- die DDR
- die BRD

Hier bezieht sich der Artikel allerdings auf Lande / Staaten / Union / Republik und ist insofern erklärbar.

Comment: +1. Eine Anmerkung zu "der Iran": Die Bezeichnung "Iran" wird mittlerweile gewöhnlicher, die Auslassung des Artikels wird in Fachkreisen begrüßt und empfohlen (z.B. [Zentrum für Iranistik bei der Uni Marburg](https://www.uni-marburg.de/de/cnms/iranistik/studium/iranohneartikel.pdf).

Comment: @marquinho Es liegt allerdings auch nach dem Lesen des Links nahe, dass sich die "Fachkreise" hier am englischen Gebrauch orientieren. Auf die Schweiz wird zum Beispiel nicht eingegangen. Der verlinkte Text atmet förmlich die implizite Behauptung, der Artikel sei bei Ländernamen irgendwie abwertend.

Comment: "*Hier ist der Artikel erklärbar*" - warum dann nicht auch "das Deutsch-land", "das Frank-reich", "die Elfenbeinküste"? :-)

Comment: "*Eine vollständige Liste gibt es [hier](https://deutschtraining.org/deutsche-grammatik/artikel/laender-mit-artikel/)*" - da fehlen ein paar, "das Vereinigte Königreich", "die Elfenbeinküste", "die Seychellen", "die Salomonen", "die Marshallinseln", "die Malediven", "die Komoren", "die Cookinseln"

Comment: @HalvarF: Mit der Bezeichnung "Iran" orientieren sie sich m.M.n. nicht so sehr am englischen, als vielmehr an den lokalen Sprachgebrauch (Farsi hat keinen bestimmten Artikel) und auf die Eigenbezeichnung. Aber das ist, zugegeben, nur eine unsystematische Anmerkung zum einzelnen Fall; ob der Artikel immer abwertend sei, ist fraglich; und was die Schweiz davon hält, weiß ich nicht :-)

Comment: @Bergi: 'warum dann nicht auch "das Deutsch-land", "das Frank-reich"' - wer hat denn gesagt, dass _diese_ Verwendung _ohne_ Artikel erklärbar, logisch, oder gar wünschenswert sei, wenn man auf einheitliche Verwendung bedacht ist?

Comment: @Bergi: Darüberhinaus bin ich von deinen zwei Kommentaren verwirrt. Im ersten klingt es, als fragtest du, wieso es _nicht_ "die Elfenbeinküste" heiße (tut es aber), im zweiten listet du ebendiese Elfenbeinküste als Beispiel für Ländernamen mit Artikeln auf.

Comment: @marquinho: Wenn im Artikel schon eine Regel wie "'Länder auf -ei' haben einen weiblichen Artikel" akzeptiert wird, wirkt es doch recht willkürzlich, Ländern auf -ine nicht dasselbe zuzugestehen - beide Endungen würde ich intuitiv mit "grammatikalisch weiblich" assoziieren.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Ich wollte nur darauf hinaus, dass die Erklärbarkeit nicht wirklich gegeben ist

Comment: @marquinho: wemm das "Zentrum für Iranistik" den Status "Expertenkreise" bei der deutschen Bezeichnung für ein Land hat, warum wurde dann die richtige Schreibweise für "Delphin"/"Delfin" nicht von Biologen entschieden, sondern von Germanisten? Und wenn wir wissen wollen, wie man zB. "Palatschinken" richtig schreibt, sollten wir dann in den Duden schauen - oder in ein Kochbuch?

Comment: @marquinho Wenn mir jetzt noch jemand erklären könnte, warum grammatikalische Eigenschaften des Farsi irgendeine Relevanz für die deutsche Grammatik haben sollten.

Answer (score 2):

Die Verwendung des Artikels ist überhaupt nicht abwertend, sondern bloß eine Frage des Geschlechts. Es ist wohl eine sehr alte Konvention, daß der sächliche bestimmte Artikel bei Ländernamen weggelassen wird, anders als bei Ländern, deren Namen männlich oder weiblich sind, oder im Plural stehen.
Interessant ist, daß bei Verwendung eines Adjektivs vor dem Ländernamen auch der sächliche Artikel wieder erscheint, z.B.: das wiedervereinigte Deutschland. Und das auch, wenn das Adjektiv Bestandteil des Ländernamens ist. Daher: das Vereinigte Königreich.

Bastian Sick hat das in seiner [Zwiebelfisch-Kolumne](https://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-abc-laendernamen-mit-artikel-laendernamen-ohne-artikel-a-327185.html) sehr gut erklärt.

Also nein, es gibt keine politische Konnotation, die Verwendung von Ukraine ohne den bestimmten Artikel wäre im Deutschen einfach nur falsch, weil der Name der Ukraine weiblichen Geschlechts ist.

Comment: Dass bei der Verwendung eines Adjektivs der Artikel wieder erscheint, scheint aus bei anderen Sprachen der Fall zu sein: "the reunited Germany", "het herenigde Duitsland". Gibt es Ländernamen, die nur männlich sind? Die Ländernamen Jemen, Iran, oder Kongo sind offenbar entweder männlich oder sächlich.

Answer (score 1):

Meine Interpretation (als deutscher Nicht-Linguist) wäre: Es ist vollständig vom Sprachgefühl abhängig, ob eine Regionsbezeichnung im Kontext der Frage mit oder ohne Artikel verwendet wird. (Die Frage "welcher Artikel gehört zu einem Nomen" würde ich als ähnlich gelagertes Beispiel sehen.)

Ein Beispiel:

- Der Satz "Ich fahre durch Deutschland" funktioniert. "Ich fahre durch das Deutschland" fühlt sich falsch an.
- "Ich fahre durch die Schweiz" funktioniert. "Ich fahre durch Schweiz" fühlt sich falsch an.

Im Beispiel "Ukraine" würde ich persönlich zu "die Ukraine" tendieren; aber ich ahne, dass sich hier die Geister scheiden könnten (analog zur Frage "die oder das Nutella?").

Insofern würde ich sagen: Nein, im Deutschen gibt es keine politische Konnotation, ob eine Länderbezeichnung mit oder ohne Artikel verwendet wird.