# Verwendung des Genitivs bei Ländern

Tags: declension

In einem Artikel über die Beziehungen zwischen Russland und der Türkei fand ich einen Abschnitt mit dem Titel

> Türkeis umstrittene Entscheidung

Der Genitiv "Türkeis" scheint zwar korrekt, klingt aber merkwürdig. Ich würde die Formulierung

> Umstrittene Entscheidung der Türkei

bevorzugen.

Bei den meisten anderen Ländern ist die Verwendung des Genitivs mit "s" völlig normal:

- Deutschlands Städte
- Ägyptens Küste
- Chinas Bevölkerung

**Gibt es hierfür eine Regel?**

Meine Vermutung: Bei Ländern, deren Namen der weibliche Artikel "die" vorangestellt wird, sollte nicht das Genitiv-s verwendet werden, sondern dem Ländernamen sollte der weibliche Genitiv-Artikel "der" vorangestellt werden.

Vgl. dazu [Hat die Verwendung des bestimmten Artikels in "die Ukraine" eine politische Konnotation?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/70411/34192)

Comment: Inwiefern beantwortet die verlinkte Frage nicht auch deine? Nur sächliche Ländernamen stehen ohne bestimmten Artikel, also müsste es "der Türkei umstrittene Entscheidung" heißen, aber natürlich wird man fast immer "die umstrittene Entscheidung der Türkei" vorziehen.

Comment: @CarstenS : Eine Ausnahme ist hier die Schweiz - nicht sächlich, aber mit Artikel. Auch bei Vereinigten Staaten / USA verwendest Du einen Artikel, obgleich sie nicht sächlich sind.

Comment: @user1934428, genau, Du hast meinen Kommentar falsch herum gelesen.

Comment: @CarstenS : Hast recht. Aber was ist mit "die Niederlande"? Gut, es ist ein Pluralwort, leitet sich aber vom Singular "das Land" (alter Plural: "die Lande") ab, sollte also sächlich sein.

Comment: @user1934428, okay, das stimmt. Genauer hätte ich sächlich Einzahl schreiben sollen, oder einfacher, dass nur „das“ weggelassen wird wenn der Landesname alleine steht. Aber das steht bestimmt alles korrekt in einer Antwort auf die Frage, die ich verlinkt habe.

Comment: @CarstenS In Deinen Kommentaren hast Du nichts verlinkt. Meinst Du den Link in der obigen Frage?

Comment: @KritikerderElche, richtig, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die Aussage

> Der Genitiv "Türkeis" scheint zwar korrekt

trifft m.E. nicht zu. Ich halte den "Genitiv" *Türkeis* für falsch, obwohl er gelegentlich in der Presse verwendet wird. Beispiele:

- Deutschlandfunk: [Türkeis Volleyballerinnen sorgen für Euphorie und Polarisierung](https://www.deutschlandfunk.de/sport-aktuell-tuerkei-lgbtq-volleyball-100.html)
- FAZ: [Recep Tayyip Erdoğan: Eigentur mit Türkeis Supercup in Saudi-Arabien](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/sport/fussball/recep-tayyip-erdo-an-eigentur-mit-tuerkeis-supercup-in-saudi-arabien-19419519.html)
- ZEIT : [Türkeis Premier Erdogan im Gespräch](https://www.zeit.de/2010/13/Erdogan)

Der Ländername "Türkei" ist zwar ein Eigenname, unterscheidet sich aber von Personennamen dadurch, dass er nur mit Artikel verwendet wird. Der "Genitiv" *Türkeis* wurde in Analogie zum Genitiv von Vornamen gebildet. Die Formulierung

> Helgas (Annas, Pauls, ...) umstrittene Entscheidung

ist korrekt. Vielleicht wurde bei der Türkei der weibliche Vorname *Amrei* als Vorbild genommen.

Substantiven, die keine Eigennamen sind, wird immer ein Artikel vorangestellt und gemeinsam mit dem Substantiv dekliniert. Beispiele für Genitiv:

- der Frau
- des Arzts

Bei Substantiven mit Genus "feminin" tritt hierbei kein End-s auf. Die Formulierung

> Fraus umstrittene Entscheidung

ist definitiv falsch. Richtig ist

> Umstrittene Entscheidung der Frau

Im Übrigen verwendet man auch bei Substantiven mit Genus "maskulin" und "neutral" keine Formulierungen wie "Arzts umstrittene Entscheidung".

Die Besonderheit von "Türkei" (und anderen Ländernamen) ist, dass das Wort - obwohl ein Eigenname - grammatisch nicht als Eigenname behandelt wird.

**PS.** [Zitat](https://gramm_de.de-academic.com/34/Der_Artikel_bei_Eigennamen) "Der Artikel bei Eigennamen":

> § 70. Von den geographischen Eigennamen werden die Städte- und Ländernamen sowie die Namen der Kontinente sächlichen Geschlechts, ferner die Namen vieler größerer Inseln ohne Artikel gebraucht.
> ... der vierte Morgen seiner Flucht fiel in jene Oktoberwoche, da in Spanien um Teruel gekämpft wurde und die japanischen Truppen in China eindrangen... (A. Seghers)
> Mit dem Erlös seines Fundes war Spoelmanns Vater nach Südamerika übergesiedelt... (Th. Mann)
> Die „Montreal“ soll untergegangen sein zwischen Dakar und Martinique. (A. Seghers)
> Der bestimmte Artikel steht immer bei folgenden geographischen Namen:
> (1) bei Ländernamen männlichen und weiblichen Geschlechts sowie bei dem Namen der Stadt Haag, der männlichen Geschlechts ist: die Schweiz, die Tschechoslowakei, die Türkei, der Iran (auch: Iran), der Haag u.a.
> [...]