# Sind „Ich denke, dass [Nebensatz]“ und „Ich denke, [Hauptsatz]“ auswechselbar?

Tags: difference, clauses

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen den folgenden Konstruktionen?

> Ich denke, dass die Katze süß ist.
>
> Ich denke, die Katze ist süß.

Sind sie immer auswechselbar, oder hängt es vom Nebensatz/Hauptsatz ab?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vorweg: Ich würde generell eher *Ich glaube, dass* oder *Ich finde, dass* (je nach Kontext) sagen. *Ich denke, dass* setzt sich zwar (leider) immer mehr durch, ist aber eigentlich ein Anglizismus, eine wörtliche Übersetzung von *I think*.

> Ich finde, dass die Katze süß ist.

Das ist die normale Konstruktion mit Nebensatz, die ist immer korrekt. In der zweiten Variante hingegen hast du zwei Hauptsätze, von denen sich aber der eine auf den anderen bezieht. Ich würde daher schreiben:

> Ich finde: Die Katze ist süß.

Etwas das du denkst, findest oder glaubst ist eigentlich so ähnlich wie etwas, das du sagst. Da würdest du ja auch sagen:

> Ich sage: "Die Katze ist süß."

Da kommt man dann wieder zur indirekten Rede:

> Er sagt, die Katze sei nicht süß.

Aber warum sollte das nicht auch beim Finden so sein?

> Er findet, die Katze sei nicht süß.

Auch hier passt die indirekte Rede, obwohl es natürlich keine gesprochenen Worte sind. Möchte man beim Direkten bleiben, sollte man wohl eher die Formulierung mit Doppelpunkt verwenden.

Comment: Das mit der indirekten Rede bei "finden" wage ich zu bezweifeln. Wenn das stimmen würde, müsste man: "Ich finde, die Katze sei süß." sagen, was eindeutig falsch ist. Oder?

Comment: @splattne: In der Tat spekuliere ich diesbezüglich etwas. Klingt "Er findet, die Katze sei nicht süß" falsch für dich? Ich bin an dieser Stelle auch unsicher. "Ich finde, die Katze ist süß" dürfte aber nicht richtig sein.

Comment: @OregonGhost Hm, je mehr ich nachdenke, desto schlechter wird meine intuitive Wahrnehmung. Ich denke gerade mal über die Grammatik nach. Ich glaube der Knackpunt ist, dass die Art des "dass" hier das Ausschlaggebende ist. Also, Regel: *"dass, wenn der Hauptsatz eine Wahrnehmungsäußerung, eine Gefühlsäußerung, ein Ausdruck des Denkens, des Wissens oder des Wollens enthält"*

Comment: @splattne: Ja, da sind wir dann wieder beim Nebensatz. Das ist auf jeden Fall unstrittig und einfacher ;)

Comment: @OregonGhost Bin mir nicht sicher, ob man die Verben einfach austauschen darf, aber ich glaube, du bist auf dem richtigen Weg. Ich versuche, ein Prototyp-Beispiel zu finden; etwa: "Peter weiß, dass Heidi stark ist." - "Peter weiß: Heidi ist stark." und nicht "Peter weiß, Heidi ist stark."

Comment: Inzwischen auch mal ein +1 von mir. Ich finde, du hast Recht. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Semantisch (sinngemäß) gibt es keinen Unterschied zwischen den beiden Varianten. Mir fällt auch kein Gegenbeispiel ein, bei dem ein Wechsel eine Änderung der Bedeutung mit sich bringen würde.

Es kann höchstens sein, dass die zweite, kürzere Variante in einigen Fällen zu Zweitdeutigkeiten führt und somit stilistisch schlechter ist.

Comment: Kannst du mir die zweideutigkeit verdeutlichen? In beiden Fällen vermute ich, dass von einer bestimmten einzelnen Katze die Rede ist.

Comment: Ich meine andere Beispiele. Es geht ja nicht nur um die Katze. Siehe Titel.

Answer (score 1):

Ich ersetze es mal durch den Namen meines Katers

```
Ich denke, dass Nemo süß ist.

Ich denke, der Nemo ist süß.
```

Beides klingt gleich richtig. Allerdings würde man beim eigenen Haustier sagen

```
Nemo ist süß.
```

Das `ich denke mal` drückt eine Vermutung aus. Zumindest sein eigenes Haustier sollte man besser kennen.

Comment: Ich habe aber keine Katze.

Comment: Ist "der Nemo" ein Typo?

Comment: Nein das ist sein Eigenname. Er ist ein Kater und Nemo bezieht sich auf Kapitän Nemo (Jules Verne).

Comment: Warum verwendet man nur den Artikel im Letztere? "... dass Nemo süß ist" vs. "der Nemo ist süß".

Comment: Bei einem Kater ist es ziemlich egal, ob ich `Nemo ist süß` oder `Der Nemo ist süß` sage. In Bayern hört man eher `Der Nemo ist süß`. Dort hieß es von unserer weiblichen Katze `Das Mauli ist süß` ( Eigentlich gaben wir ihr den chinesischen Namen Mei-Li ).

Comment: @Tim: In dem Satz *Ich denke, der Nemo ist süß* müsste man den Artikel in der Tat weglassen. Sh. auch hier: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/271/articles-in-real-life

Comment: Außer im Fall, dass es zwei Katzen mit dem Namen Nemo gibt. In dem Zusammenhang ändert sich auch der Gebrauch wenn man über Personen spricht. Dann kann man sagen `Der Peter dort spricht gut englisch`.

Comment: Hallo Bernd, Du hast in deinem Posting ein paar kleine Fehler. Es muss *ersetzen* heißen, "ersätzen" ist falsch. Ich würde auch den Artikel aus dem Beispielsatz streichen oder zumindest darauf hinweisen, dass es landschaftlich ist, denn hochdeutsch ist es nicht. Auch Dein Beispiel mit den zwei Petern überzeugt mich nicht, aber das wäre vielleicht wert, in einer eigenen Frage erörtert zu werden.

Comment: @fzwo danke für die Korrektur von erserzen, hätte ich der Rechtschreibreform glatt zugetraut. Ich sagte klingt richtig, und nicht es ist richtig. Das relativiert es auf mein subjektives Sprachgefühl. Mit den beiden Petern gebe ich dir auch Recht das sollte man tun.

Comment: Was ist mit "Ich finde Nemo süss."? Macht formal wenig Sinn, denn man sucht die Katze ja nicht...und ist trotzdem sehr verbreitet. (Also...jetzt nicht die Katze Nemo, oder das Süssfinden von einzelnen Katzen (naja...), sondern die Formulierung.)

Comment: @theBlastOne Du darfst auch ein Mädel süss finden. Stell doch dazu einfach eine neue Frage.

Comment: Stimmt auffallend. I shut up, not a question of mine :)

Comment: Süß finden ist eine spontane Gefühlsregung, und erfordert nicht, dass man das Tier kennt. I.d.R. kann man eine Katze in einer Sekunde süß finden (im Ggs. zu Hunden, die irgendwie immer eklig sind). ;) Besonders süße Katzen schaffen es allerdings, dass man zu sinnieren beginnt, *wie süß* die Katze doch ist, wie sie das macht, und wie es kommt, dass sie ausschaut, als wisse sie selbst genau, und würde zu ihrem Vorteil Gebrauch ... - also man kann sich selbst dabei ertappen, wie man die Katze süß findet, weil es lange andauern kann, und oft vorkommt. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Ersetze mal das "Ich" durch ein anderes Pronomen und der Unterschied sollte offensichtlicher werden.
"Ich denke, die Katze ist süß." ist schlicht falsche Punktuation, richtig wäre: "Ich denke: "Die Katze ist süß.""

Bezüglich der Konstruktionen "dass" + Indikativ, ["dass" +] Konjunktiv I, und ["dass" +] Konjunctiv II: Alle drei berichten über etwas, die Erste drückt aber zusätzlich noch aus, dass Du gleicher Meinung bist, die Zweite lässt das offen und mit der Dritten äußerst Du Zweifel.
Wenn Du über Deine eigenen gegenwärtigen Gedanken berichtest bist Du gewöhnlich gleicher Meinung mit Dir selbst (hoffe ich).

Comment: »Du denkst, die Katze ist süß« ist ein Satz, der syntaktisch, semantisch, grammatikalisch und zeichensetzerisch völlig in Ordnung ist.