# Are sentences with and without "dass" equally common?

Tags: style

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sind „Ich denke, dass [Nebensatz]“ und „Ich denke, [Hauptsatz]“ auswechselbar?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/857/sind-ich-denke-dass-nebensatz-und-ich-denke-hauptsatz-auswechselbar)

Are these two sentences used equally in informal conversation, or is one form preferred over the other? What about in more formal written German?

1. "Ich glaube, ich gehe heute ins Kino."
2. "Ich glaube, dass ich heute ins Kino gehe."

Comment: In informal conversation, one would use (1) almost exclusively. 
For me it's a hard to think about an example of (2) in an informal conversation, an example would be: 
A: "Ich glaube" <silence> B: "Du glaubst was?" A: "Ich glaube, dass ich heute ins Kino gehe."

Comment: I disagree with @0x6d64. "Ich glaube, dass ..." is common usage. Ich glaube dass es heute noch schneit. Ich glaube dass es dann aber rasch Frühling wird. Ich glaube dass das nix wird, mit der Frage.

Comment: @userunknown: After giving it some thought, you are probably right.