# Usage of "aussehen"

Tags: verb

There is a sentence in a book about Harry Potter:

> Tante Petunia sagte oft, dass Dudley aussehe wie ein kleiner Engel - Harry sagte oft, Dudley sehe aus wie ein Schwein mit Perücke.

Could someone please explain me:

(1) Why is there `aussehe` and then `sehe aus`?

(2) Is `aussehe`/ `sehe aus` Präteritum? I known sehen-sah-gesehen, could someone give me three forms of `aussehen`?

(3) Is that correct to leave out second `dass`? Is that correct because first `dass` exists?

Comment: [This](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:aussehen) is your answer to question number 2.

Comment: You can add or omit "dass", as e.g. stated [here](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/en/grammar/sentence-structure/dependent-clauses/indirect-speech)

Comment: Regarding (1), _dass_ introduces a subordinate clause, and subordinate clauses have different word order.

Comment: @chirlu I thought that `dass` could be implied (but skipped) in the second part, but if it were implied, the clause would be surbordinate. But it seems it is not. Is that true that there is one main and one subordinate clause in the first part and two main clauses in the second?

Comment: To answer your question: it is a combination of a [separable verb](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/160/wie-kann-man-wissen-ob-ein-verb-trennbar-ist)  with usage of *Konjunktiv I* in [indirect speech](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4592/konjunktiv-i-vs-sagen-dass-in-reported-speech) that may have confused you here.