# Is "lässt heller erscheinen" appropriate?

Tags: word-usage

The context is:

> Was mir am Besten an seinem Zimmer gefällt, ist der riesige Spiegel, der an der Wand hängt.
>   Ich denke, es **lässt** den Raum grösser und **heller** erscheinen.

I'm not sure if *lässt* and *heller* work in this context.

Comment: As it stands, this question is going to be closed as it is asking for proofreading. To prevent this, please ask about a specific problem you are having with this sentence.

Comment: Compare http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/857/sind-ich-denke-dass-nebensatz-und-ich-denke-hauptsatz-auswechselbar. Also, what does “es” refer to? Voting to close now.

Comment: We are getting closer. There are still two separate questions here. Also please tell us what your problems with a word or construction are, so we can address these problems. We like questions about a single issue here that may be helpful to other people.

Comment: I assume the question is about the collocation "lässt heller erscheinen", thus I moved it into the title. If I'm mistaken feel free to rollback my change (you shouldn't, however, rollback my typo and punctuation fixes ;) )

Comment: @Em1: Ah, I haven’t even considered that those could belong to one aspect (which shows once more, why you should explain what your issues are).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is completely correct. But, since it is "der Spiegel" you should write:
Ich denke, er läßt ...

Comment: Do you have to switch er and läßt around?

Comment: No, you would only do that if it would be a question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is the original question, yes, "heller erscheinen lassen" is totally correct.

As for the rest of the sentences, definitely replace "es" with "er" - lots of objects are considered masculine or feminine in Germany and are therefore referred to as such.

Personally, I would also leave out the "der an der Wand hängt.". Where else would a mirror be?

Comment: Some people have a mirror on the ceiling or as the door of their wardrobe, so there are options. But yes: it is slightly redundant.