# Wie sagt man „I think I understand“?

Tags: english-to-german, sentence-structure

If:

> Ich glaube = I believe
> Ich denke = I think
> Ich verstehe = I understand

Then is it simply:

> Ich glaube ich verstehe. (I believe I understand)
> Or: Ich denke ich verstehe.

Or must you not omit the *that*?

> Ich glaube dass ich verstehe. (I believe that I understand)
> Or: Ich denke dass ich verstehe.

And finally, the comma is required yes?

> Ich denke, dass ich verstehe.
>
> Ich denke, dass ich muss etwas bier trinken … ?

Comment: *'Ich denke, dass ich etwas Bier trinken muss… '*

Comment: In German: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/857/sind-ich-denke-dass-nebensatz-und-ich-denke-hauptsatz-auswechselbar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two subjects, two verbs -> two clauses...

> ***'Ich glaube (denke), ich verstehe'***

is short for

> ***'Ich glaube (denke), dass ich verstehe***'

Because of the same subject in main-clause and sub-clause it wouldn't be necessary to use a conjugated verb in the sub-clause. An infinitive-construction would do the trick. So in *'proper'* German I would say:

> - ***Ich glaube zu verstehen!***

---

If this all were in a colloquial speech you could also say:

> - ***(Ah), verstehe!***

---

Although this sounds more like you are pretty sure if you don't use a rather questioning tone. There is some tiny little doubt or *hesitation* in ***'ich glaube (denke)...'***

Comment: "Because of the same subject in main-clause and sub-clause it wouldn't be necessary to use a conjugated verb in the sub-clause." Does this mean for "I think he is eating" you *would* conjugate "eating" but not if you said "I think I am eating"?  (I.e. "Ich denke, dass er isst", "Ich denke, dass ich essen", but NOT "Ich denke, dass ich esse" ?)

Comment: @Tom: There **are** some verbs that transfer the 'right' (to take part in the correspondence check between main-clause and sub-clause) to the object, but *'think'* is not one of them. So e.g. *'**Ich** glaube zu träumen'* means *'**Ich** glaube, dass **ich** träume'*. But verbs of sensory perception do, e.g. *'Ich höre **ihn** die Stiege herunter kommen'* means *'Ich höre, dass **er** die Stiege herunter kommt'*. - So *'Ich glaube, dass ich esse'* is correct - and so is *'Ich glaube zu essen'*...

Comment: @Tom: Of course, you don't say: *'(Ah), essen...'* like you can say *'(Ah), verstehe...'* ;-)

Comment: Ah, verstehe! :)

Comment: @Tom: Now you really got it... ;-)

Comment: Went looking for more info on "zu" and found this article that might be useful for others who stumble on here.  I had read it before but didn't really understand it's application until now!  Thanks for helping my understanding :)  http://marathonsprachen.com/zu-is-more-than-a-just-a-preposition-using-zu-constructions/

Comment: @Tom: Since the Phoenician have invented *'money'* and StackEx *'rewards for the perfect answer'* it is actually very easy to show one's appreciation... ;-)