# How to understand this sentence - "Ich denke die nehme ich"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

The full phrase looks like this `Die Pizza sieht lecker aus. Ich denke die nehme ich`. It should mean `The pizza looks delicious. I think I'll go with that`.

I would understand `Ich denke, daß ich nehme sie`, but I cannot get the form I mentioned above.

Comment: The english translation is correct. However in a subclause with "dass" it would be something like "Ich denke, dass ich diese nehme" - which would just feel very unwieldy saying that out loud. So we would usually shorten this to "Ich denke, die nehm' ich." PS: Word order of subject predicate and object can change a lot depending on what kind of sentence it is in german.

Comment: Related, in German https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/857/sind-ich-denke-dass-nebensatz-und-ich-denke-hauptsatz-auswechselbar

Comment: @Adwaenyth please do not answer in comments.

Comment: @infinitezero that's not really an answer, just the gut feeling of a native speaker. ;)

Answer (score 5):

## Simple part

Many verbs that take subordinate clauses can take clauses that look like main clauses.

> 1. Ich glaube, **dass** der Termin verschoben **wurde**.
> 2. Ich glaube, der Termin **wurde** verschoben.

This creates a terminological problem. **Nebensatz** usually refers to clauses that are **subordinate** and **verb-final**, just as in the first sentence above. **Hauptsatz**, on the other hand, usually refers to **main clauses** (i.e. not subordinate, but independent) that, in the case of declarative clauses, are **verb-second**.

In the second sentence above, we have a **subordinate** clause with "main clause word order", i.e. **verb-second**. Grammarians have come up with the term **uneingeleiteter Nebensatz**, with *uneingeleitet* referring to the missing conjunction.

## Difficult part

Although the two sentences above are equivalent in meaning, this is not always the case. In fact, for your example, I find

> #Ich denke, dass ich die nehme.

close to unacceptable with the intended meaning of communicating an order to a waiter. (The sentence is fine when communicating to someone else which pizza you intend to order.)

One assumption that would explain this discrepancy is this: When the content of the matrix clause is sufficiently "light" or close to redundant (after all, opinions or beliefs can be expressed without prefixing *ich denke* or *ich glaube*), the illocutionary force of the sentence is carried by the embedded clause when that clause is able to do so, i.e. when it has the form of a main clause (verb-second).

In other words,

> Ich denke, die nehme ich.

is equivalent to

> Die nehme ich!

but

> Ich denke, dass ich die nehme.

is like

> Ich gedenke, diese Pizza zu nehmen.
> Ich spiele mit dem Gedanken, diese Pizza zu nehmen.

in so far as that it can't be used to relay an order to a waiter.

For the *terminus technicus* of illocution see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illocutionary_act).

Answer (score 2):

I am not a native German speaker (learning the language myself), but I noticed something strange: 'nehme' usually means 'with me' (ex. 'zum mitnehmen' -> 'take away' /'take it to go'/...) so the more accurate translation would be: I think I'll take it (with me).

**Ich denke** - I think/ I consider

**die** - refers to the pizza

**nehme ich** - I'll have it / I'll take / take with me

But yes, for me also it doesn't come natural to say it like that.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Sorry to disapppoint you: in this context it is "I choose this pizza" ;-)

Comment: If Iam not mistaken "nehmen" also means to "have something" especially when talking about food and drink. (Ich nehme ein bier)

Comment: @ShegitBrahm I am also not a native English speaker, but I think the context is quite similar (the end result is that the pizza seller will give you the pizza :). Also, I think that John Ronald (and myself) need(ed) a more literal translation for better understanding, and in you context 'Ich denke' can not be recognized.

Comment: @theCuriousOne: oh, sorry, I refered only to "die nehme ich".

Answer (score 1):

`... den/die/das nehme ich` refers to "I choose this" = "Ich wähle den/die/das ... (aus)."

The first half `ich denke` is just "I consider/think about to".

So yes, it is similiar to the given english description `I think I'll go with that`.

So it is an expression of choice rather than a future movement of me with the object.

See e.g. [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/nehmen) no 4 a)

Answer (score 1):

There is a comma missing in the sentence. The correct sentence is:

> Ich denke, die nehme ich.

This is called *Objektsatz*. The subordinate clause after the comma is the object of the main clause.

Literally translated: *I think I take them* or maybe rather *I think I will take them*, considering that English is more strict with respect to future tense than German.